# UITableViewCell indexPathForCell: crashing app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method on my UITableView, I have this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Ok");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor carrotColor] selectedColor:[UIColor sunflowerColor] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSArray *listaDeEncuestas = [defaults objectForKey:@"encuestas"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [listaDeEncuestas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    cell.separatorHeight = 0.0f;

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldFlatFontOfSize:17];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor cloudsColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"encuesta"];
    return cell;
}
```

The app crashes in simulator when this line is executed:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor carrotColor] selectedColor:[UIColor sunflowerColor] style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This is de Log output:

```
2013-06-28 16:02:49.702 Encuestas[5447:a0b] -[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad77ca0
2013-06-28 16:05:18.311 Encuestas[5447:3c0b] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2013-06-28 16:05:20.171 Encuestas[5447:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad77ca0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x21449b8 0x1ec58b6 0x21e0c13 0x2134cfb 0x21348de 0x13a98 0x115553a 0x1ed781f 0x4c2974 0x4b67ee 0x4c28bf 0x12032b2 0x1130062 0x112ec52 0x112eb24 0x112ebac 0x112dc6f 0x112dbd1 0x112e91b 0x1131e42 0x11f6442 0x11281b9 0x1128334 0x112859e 0x1132697 0x10e8824 0x10e9b5e 0x10ffa6c 0x10fffd9 0x10eb7d5 0x25f5906 0x25f5411 0x20c03e5 0x20c011b 0x20eab30 0x20ea10d 0x20e9f3b 0x10e92b1 0x10eb4eb 0xd07d 0x2d5d725)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The code works just fine in iOS 6, so I was wondering, why is this crashing on iOS 7? Is there anything that I'm missing from the documentation?

Comment: For questions about iOS7, which is still under NDA, please visit the Apple Developer forums. But you do have a nice helpful error message there that tells you exactly what's wrong. UITableViewCell has never responded to the selector indexPathForCell. That's a UITableView method.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say anything about iOS 7, because NDA and everything, but if you look into the `FUICellBackgroundView` class, you will notice the following on line 30, followed by an invocation of `indexPathForCell:`, which is where your app crashes:

```
UITableView* tableView = (UITableView*)self.superview.superview;
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)self.superview];
```

Source: https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit/blob/52a283435801e4fd45d9d6835743d7b0caa40db5/Classes/ios/FUICellBackgroundView.m#L30

Now, the problem arises that there is no guarantee over the view hierarchy of `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell`'s it houses, and it appears like `FlatUIKit` is making an assumption about it that is not true. The simplest fix would probably adding a check wether the returned view is a `UITableView`, and if not, simply walk up the hierarchy until you are either at the window or the housing table view (in the first case, throw an exception).

Fork it, add the check, submit a pull request and be happy that you did something for open source that day :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in iOS 7 "`configureFlatCellWithColor`" in `UITableViewCell` instead you should be using following implementation

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]

if (cell == nil) 
{

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: I'm using FlatUIKit, that's where that method comes from.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the implementation even if you are using FlatUIKit. The problem occurred in following line of code, CFNetwork SSLHandshake which is internal to the framework and it happened when you are trying to connect to SSL server but the handshake failed. Are you fetching some data over network to render it to the tableview? If you are, then you need to look at whether you are receiving something from server end or not.

Comment: -1 Please read the error message more carefully. Especially the one that mentions the exception that was thrown that terminated the app.

Comment: Yes indeed but if anything wents wrong inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, it throws exception at [UITableViewCell indexPathForCell] please validate it and then please down vote. I have validated it besides please have a look inside FlatUIKit implementation.

Comment: @Idindu Sorry, not going to remove the downvote. The SSL handshake failed almost two seconds prior to the exception being thrown, it's VERY unlikely that the code path from the failed SSL handshake ended in the exception being thrown. Also, if you take a look into the method, you'll notice that there is no networking code in it whatsoever.

Comment: But you haven't noticed that following line of code is executed before handshake failed "2013-06-28 16:02:49.702 Encuestas[5447:a0b] -[UITableViewCell indexPathForCell:]"

Comment: Which happened *minutes* prior... Please read the full question an attached error messages and code before answering.

Comment: I agreed with your statement about there is no networking being involved during cellForRowAtIndexPath method execution. But if you look at FlatUIKit implementation, there is hardly anything which causes it to crash.

Comment: Are you serious?! It took me one minute to find [this](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit/blob/52a283435801e4fd45d9d6835743d7b0caa40db5/Classes/ios/FUICellBackgroundView.m#L30) line of code, which is indirectly invoked by `configureFlatCellWithColor:`.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] == 7.0)
{
    tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview.superview.superview;

}
else
{
     tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
}
```